# How to make calculator in HTTP headers with Nginx server?

Tags: http, nginx, get, http-headers

How to make calculator with HTTP headers and nginx? For example, I have nginx server, and when I send GET request with my custom additional header (like `Calc`) with value like `2+3`, how to make it respond with the right answer? As far as I understand in Linux we already have backend for this, `bc`. Then how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: A well-formed question will include what you have tried and what the result was (in addition to your goal).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the button code:

```
<input type="button" value="=" onclick="cal.display.value=eval(cal.display.value) ">
```

Comment: How does this solve OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my one doesn't work.

Try the following:

```
#include <ngx_config.h>
#include <ngx_core.h>
#include <ngx_http.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

typedef struct {
    ngx_str_t calc_header;
} ngx_http_calc_loc_conf_t;

static char *ngx_http_calc(ngx_conf_t *cf, ngx_command_t *cmd, void *conf);

static ngx_command_t ngx_http_calc_commands[] = {
    {
        ngx_string("calc"),
        NGX_HTTP_MAIN_CONF|NGX_HTTP_SRV_CONF|NGX_HTTP_LOC_CONF|NGX_CONF_TAKE1,
        ngx_http_calc,
        NGX_HTTP_LOC_CONF_OFFSET,
        0,
        NULL
    },
    ngx_null_command
};

static ngx_http_module_t ngx_http_calc_module_ctx = {
    NULL,                          /* preconfiguration */
    NULL,                          /* postconfiguration */

    NULL,                          /* create main configuration */
    NULL,                          /* init main configuration */

    NULL,                          /* create server configuration */
    NULL,                          /* merge server configuration */

    NULL,                          /* create location configuration */
    NULL                           /* merge location configuration */
};

ngx_module_t ngx_http_calc_module = {
    NGX_MODULE_V1,
    &ngx_http_calc_module_ctx,    /* module context */
    ngx_http_calc_commands,       /* module directives */
    NGX_HTTP_MODULE,              /* module type */
    NULL,                          /* init master */
    NULL,                          /* init module */
    NULL,                          /* init process */
    NULL,                          /* init thread */
    NULL,                          /* exit thread */
    NULL,                          /* exit process */
    NULL,                          /* exit master */
    NGX_MODULE_V1_PADDING
};

static ngx_int_t
ngx_http_calc_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r)
{
    ngx_http_calc_loc_conf_t *calc_conf;
    ngx_str_t calc_header;
    ngx_str_t result;
    ngx_buf_t *b;
    ngx_chain_t out;
    int fds[2];
    int ret;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];

    calc_conf = ngx_http
```